# Does さえ mean "even" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, particle-さえ

I encountered the following in our daily reading.

> どのような企業{きぎょう}も、創業期{そうぎょうき}には全社員が昼食をとること **さえ** 忘れてしまうほど、忙しくフル回転していたものです。
>
> In a business, a person was so busy that he forgot to eat lunch **even** lunch. (Not sure if translation is correct.)

From what my friend explained, the さえ means "even" or similar to ほど. Using a similar sentence he explained that さえ was only.

> 私はお酒 **さえ** あれば、幸せです。
>
> *Even* if I have I only have sake, I am happy.

How is さえ used? I think it is synonymous with ほど.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`さえ` is similar to `も` for many cases. It means "even".

> どのような企業も<sub>1</sub>、創業期には全社員が昼食をとること**さえ<sub>2</sub>**忘れてしまうほど<sub>3</sub>、忙しくフル回転していたものです。
>
> - Even(も<sub>1</sub>) for any enterprise in its establishment period all the workers are so busy in full operation to the extent(ほど<sub>3</sub>) that they will forget even(さえ<sub>2</sub>) to have lunch.

However there is a special thing that `さえ` does when used with a conditional clause. When in a conditional clause it expresses "If only", "as long as".

> 私はお酒**さえ**あれば、幸せです。
>
> - If only I have *sake*, I am happy.
> - As long as I have *sake*, I am happy.
>
> Do note that さえ with a conditional clause happens most with ば-conditional, and less frequently with たら-conditional and なら-conditional, and never with と-conditional.

Comment: I am thinking that さえ may mean せず. I saw on some site that さえあれば is equivalent to なければ

Comment: @Nap. No, most definitely not when they're isolated like that. They are not equivalent at all.

Answer (score 8):

As @Flaw mentioned, `さえ` is similar to `も` meaning "even" (it can be combined with other particles as well).  However, it carries the nuance of referring to a/the most "basic" or "obvious" thing in the context.  Here are some examples:

> - 先週の病気は本当に辛【つら】かった。水**さえ**飲めなかった。　→　"My illness last week was really bad.  I couldn't **even** drink water!"
>
>   - When one is sick, you expect them not to be able to drink alcohol, soda, etc.  But water should be OK for most people.  **Even water**, the most basic thing was intolerable for this person.
> - えりこは親友の花子**にさえ**知らせずに外国へ旅立った。　→　"Eriko left on a trip to a foreign country without telling **even** her best friend Hanako."
>
>   - You'd expect her to not tell her co-workers, acquaintances, etc.  But best friends usually tell each other everything, and she didn't tell **even** her.
> - 山の上には夏**でさえ**雪が残っている。　→　"**Even** if it's summer, there is snow left on the top of the mountain."
>
>   - You expect snow to be on top of a mountain in winter, and some leftover in the spring.  But usually by summer it's all gone, but for this mountain the snow remains **even** then.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the other answers, I believe that `どの～も` can also be translated to be "no matter (what/who etc)...", for example:

> **どのような**企業**も**、創業期には全社員が昼食をとること**さえ**忘れてしまう**ほど**、忙しくフル回転していたものです。
>
> **No matter what the form** of [business/enterprise], in the [founding period/start-up period] all of the employees are of a fired-on-all-cylinders busyness **even to the [point/extent]** of forgetting to have lunch.

[Space ALC defines](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE+%E3%82%82/UTF-8/) `どの～も` as:

> any and every (an emphasized expression of "any")