# 「お前がいてくれればいい。お前さえ」

Tags: translation, meaning

> お前がいてくれればいい。お前さえ…

For context: These are words spoken by a woman who is about to move somewhere far away from her brother, whom she’s very close to.  Her brother is upset they will be so far apart and told her that their bond is unbreakable just before she spoke the above line.

Parsing the sentence:

> お前が – You
>
> いて (is this 居て?) – to stay
>
> くれれば (is this 暮れれば?) – if in the end
>
> いい – does this describe a hope or wish?

Does it say something like: I hope you continue to stay (here) in the end.

> お前さえ – does さえ mean even as explained in the answers here: [Does さえ mean "even" in the following sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4864/does-%E3%81%95%E3%81%88-mean-even-in-the-following-sentence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> お前が – You
>
> いて – to be present(by my side)
>
> くれれば (くれる(to be given) + ば(conditional)) – if you "give me the present" of (being by my side)
>
> いい – good
>
> さえ - only
>
> It would be good enough for you to be by my side. Only you.