# Help breaking down えむさえいけそうなら

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances

In the script I'm translating, Emu and Tsukasa are practicing a scene for a play where Emu has to jump from a tree to a window. After the rehearsal, Tsukasa says

> とはいえ、やはり高さがあると緊張感が違うな。
> えむさえいけそうなら、本番でも無理なくできるように、
> 何度か挑戦しておいたほうがよさそうだが……

I'm having a lot of trouble with theえむさえいけそうなら. I first translated it as "If Emu can do it," but I don't have a lot of confidence in that

Comment: えむ (name) + [さえ (particle)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4864) + いけそう (=  いける  - most likely [this one](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B) - + [suffix 〜そう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/607)) + [なら](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/393)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic translation of "えむさえいけそうなら" is indeed "as long as Emu can do it", but this "it" refers to not the jump itself but the additional rehearsal Tsukasa is suggesting. Read it as "as long as you can still afford the time and energy (for the additional jump rehearsal)".